# AngularJS: How to access input[date] min attribute within custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm trying to get write access of `<input type="date"` min attribute within my custom directive value.
As I know input[date] element is directive to. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D
So access by $(elem).attr('min') is not right way. 
How can I access input[date] min attribute within my directive?

JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/musuk/Lbbtyjod/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/ho1bL823/)

As per your directive:

use `attrs.myDirective` to access minvalue inside your directive link function. To access min date:  `attrs.min` and to set min date               `attrs.$set('min', '2015-03-02')`

```
.directive("myDirective", function(){
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
       scope: {
           minValue: "=myDirective"
       },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch('minValue', function(){
              console.log(attrs.myDirective);
              // Set min here
              attrs.$set('min', '2015-03-02');
          });
      }
    };
});
```